# Can't change Model Reference from GUI

Tags: matlab, simulink

EDIT: I decided to add screenshots of the important parts of the model, hopefully that will help clear things up.

---

I launch a model from a GUI, and depending on what options are selected in the GUI, some model references should change. Currently, the model reference is set up as follows:

[image: model reference]

I then define the following workspace variables in the model launch script:

[image: workspace]
[image: variant definitions]
Despite that, I get the following error:

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

According to MATLAB documentation for Simulink.Variant(), the variant condition must be:

> a boolean expression that references at least one base workspace
>   variable or parameter ([Reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.variant-class.html))

Your error message is telling you that you are failing to define an appropriate variant condition. You define `cs_Version` in your callback, but it does not exist in the base workspace. You must assign `cs_Version` to the base workspace, using the `assignin` method:

```
assignin ( 'base' , 'cs_Version' , cs_Version );
```

[This piece of MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/define-and-configure-variants.html) describes a model that uses variant controls `mode` and `version`, which must be assigned to the base workspace using the command line.

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried this and it did not solve the issue. I've tried 'base', 'modelworkspace' and both.

Comment: I have now changed the code to this:

`assignin('base','CoolSys1',Simulink.Variant('cs_Version == 0'))`

`assignin('base','CoolSys2',Simulink.Variant('cs_Version == 1'))`

`assignin('base','cs_Version',get(handles.ShutterEnableButton,'Value'))`

Same error message.